# validate a that a long string has enough breakable spaces for display

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, validation

I was having issues with printing table content where users had entered garbage strings without spaces, so I was unable to word-wrap table cell content in a consistant way... therefore I wanted to validate the input before it got to the print stage, avoiding CSS that was not great or fully supported by the print engine.

I wanted to limit contiguous characters so I came up with this solution but not sure if it is really the best way to go about this...

```
const limit = 25; // an abitrary number

/* a large chunk of text maybe containing 
spaces to be aligned with data in a table */
let str = some_user_input;

/* split the string to array values using 
any whitespace (added 'g' just for safety sake) */

if(str.length){
 let spaced = str.split(/\s+/g);

 //check we have array

 if(spaced.length){
  //check array items for exceeding contiguous character limit
  for(let i = 0; i < spaced.length; i++){
    if(spaced[i].length > limit){
      return false;
    }
  }//endLoop
 }
 else{
    if(str.length > limit) return false;
 }
}
return true;
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a good place to get opinions on working code.

Comment: you could also use some instead of the for loop, e.g. `return !spaced.some(el => el.length > limit)` - also i think you dont need to differentiate between the array being empty and filled

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of codereview.stackexchange..., next time will consider posting there for this type of question. And the online functions do seem like a lot more efficient use of time :) Thanks both.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using regexp, I would probably just using one to check if there are contiguous characters without whitespace in a string. Something like:

```
const limit = 4;
const reLimit = new RegExp(`\\S{${limit},}`);

const validate = (str) => !reLimit.test(str);

console.log(validate("foo bar")) // true
console.log(validate("foo barz")) // false
```